# Outer join 2 data frames by multiple columns in R

Tags: r, merge, outer-join

Could anyone help to explain me this issue. I have 2 dataframes: **mail_sent:1901 rows** and **client_return_race: 1663 rows**. I want to merge these dataframes together and all rows in mail_sent should be show.

These 2 dataframes have 3 same column: **CLIENT_ID, CAMPAIGN_NAME, TIME**. I want to merge 2 dataframes based on 3 same columns above. The below is my code.

The code runs well however, the result of merging (mail_race) is 1663 not 1901. I expect it should show 1901 rows because I mentioned all.mail_sent=all/ all.mail_sent=TRUE in the code. It seems that the merge is inner join not outer join.

```
  mail_race<-merge(mail_sent,client_return_race,by.mail_sent=c("CLIENT_ID","CAMPAIGN_NAME","TIME"),
             by.client_return_race=c("CLIENT_ID","CAMPAIGN_NAME","TIME")
             ,all.mail_sent=TRUE)
```

Comment: Change `all.mail_sent=TRUE` to `all.x=TRUE`. For more info, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Comment: Argument names never change within a function.

Comment: If it works for you, copy the comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this one it may help you

mail_race<-merge(mail_sent,client_return_race,all.x = T ,all.y = T)
```